# Cassandra Error during truncate: Cannot achieve consistency level ALL

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I'm using Cassandra 2.1.9 Keyspace

```
WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '4'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Now one node is down and i want to truncate one of the tables. How can i do it? I cannot start my 4th node now. How can i prevent such problem in future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer is that you need to have all nodes up to execute truncate command.
Documentation states:
*Note: The consistency level must be set to ALL prior to performing a TRUNCATE operation. All replicas must remove the data.*

If you really want to truncate table you will first have to decommission that downed node and remove it from the ring.

Comment: Hello, for cassandra newbies, could you elaborate or point to what this means?

Comment: This means that there is a node in the cluster that is not behaving normally. You can find out which node by running `nodetool status`. Healthy nodes will show up as "UP" (Up/Normal). If any node has another status, you should determine why.

Comment: I've "TruncateError: Error during truncate: Cannot achieve consistency level ALL" but all nodes are "UN". So, they must be another explanation.